# Communication between classes in an android project

Tags: android

I've been struggling to solve a problem for over a week.

I have a main activity with 3 child classes which extends View.
When a touch event happens at a View class, calling a certain method in other 2 View classes synchronize with the event. But I have no idea how to call the certain method.  In other words, I don't know how to communicate between classes extends View.

Does anyone know how to figure it out ?
Any comments would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to learn about listeners http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app

Comment: what kinda listener is useful for communication between classes extends View?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity create a instance of that class of whose method you want to access and call that method..

Lets assume the 3 classes where classone, classtwo and classthree and each class has a method named method.

in your activity

```
classone test = new classone();

test.method();
```

Comment: please get me online if you need any assistance raksi004@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I guess I didn't make my problem very clear. Here's what happened. Of course, I constructed every child classes in the beginning. And a touch event happens at child class A. And then a certain method in other 2 child classes is called and some values is changed by the value coming from class A. How can I do this?

Comment: when you say classes do you mean Activities or just java classes.  i mean do they extend Activity as superclass

Comment: one main class extends Activity and 3 other classes extends View.

Comment: your email id or anything so that we can communicate in a better way

Comment: you cannot extend it to view.  i want to know what you actually trying to implement

Comment: raksi004@gmail.com. i dont use gtalk here in ma office

Comment: oh i get it. then which one ??