# How to use saved instance state and restore instance state?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation

I have an application with a tab activity. The activity hosts 2 activities with a list of items. I have implemented checkboxes to each of the items also. On orientation change, I have set the tab activity to be oriented to the left hand side of the screen. ie. the tab activity and the child activity are recreated. If i press the menu button to display the check boxes and checks a few items and if the orientation is changed, the checked items will not be shown in the check boxes. I handled the display of checkboxes while orientation change using the SharedPreferences.

I am putting the checked items to an arraylist. the arraylist cannot be transacted through the SharedPrefereces.

I want the checked items to remain checked on orientation change.

Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store this arraylist in the host Activity through a interface like this: [Custom event listener on Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app) . But if there aren't so many checkboxes I would divide arraylist into simple kay-value preferences and store them  as a Shared Preferences.

Comment: The tab activity is also getting recreated while orientation change. Are you really sure about storing the arraylist in the host activity would work?