# Callbacks in C# android

Tags: c#, java, android

I have implemented callbacks on Handler(in java). I need to implement the same on c#(Xamarin). But as of now I am unable to find any solution to how I can do this in C#. I am new to c# hence have very little knowledge.

here is the java code:-

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
      if (msg.what == MSG_SURFACE_CREATED)
      {
        contentWidth = 0;
        contentHeight = 0;
        requestLayout();
        return true;
      } 
      else
      {
        Log.w("Unknown msg.what: " + msg.what);
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Any idea can i implement the same in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events is the way to go (which uses delegates).  Here is some sample code:

```
class CallingClass
{
    private SurfaceCreatingClass m_surfacecreatingclass;

    public CallingClass()
    {
        m_surfacecreatingclass = new SurfaceCreatingClass();
        m_surfacecreatingclass.SurfaceCreatedHandler += OnFinished;
        m_surfacecreatingclass.CreateSurface();
    }

    void OnFinished(int iMessageWhat)
    {
        if (iMessageWhat == SurfaceCreatingClass.MSG_SURFACE_CREATED)
        {
            contentWidth = 0;
            contentHeight = 0;
            RequestLayout();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("Unknown msg.what: " + iMessageWhat);
        }
    }
}

class SurfaceCreatingClass
{
    public delegate void SurfaceCreatedDelegate(int iWhat);
    public event SurfaceCreatedDelegate SurfaceCreatedHandler;
    public const int MSG_SURFACE_CREATED = 1;

    public void CreateSurface()
    {
        /////////////////////////////
        // Surface creation code here
        // ...
        /////////////////////////////

        if (SurfaceCreatedHandler != null)
            SurfaceCreatedHandler(MSG_SURFACE_CREATED);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, but Iam sorry as I am very new to c#. Can you guide me on how I can go about with my code in the question?

Comment: I've modified the code to look more like your original example, though it's still fundamentally the same as it was before.

Answer (score -1):

IN Xamarin You still will use this " inline " approach, defined by the keyword "delegate".
This is, because, callbacks are function pointers, c# supports this, java not, and xamarin also not, BUT tries to spawn a bridge.
Delegates in xamarin are described in here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/

Comment: thanx for your attention. It will be helpful if you could give me an example related to my code in java.

Comment: There are plenty in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app

The approach is called "observer-observable-pattern".

In the xamarin studion You can download "common samples". They also cover this topic.