# Android Color Picker current color value is not updating

Tags: android, color-picker

i am trying to get current selected color it does not pick the color on 1st selection but some how it is selected when i reopen the color dialog i.e on every new selection(color selection) previous selection becomes current selected color.

```
void openDialog(boolean supportsAlpha,int color) {
        AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, color, supportsAlpha, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myActivity.this.color = color;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

This part from above example , `myActivity.this.color = color;` is where i am trying to set color.

**USAGE**

```
 openDialog(false,color);
 drawView.setColor(color);



 public void setColor(int newColor) {
        invalidate();
        drawPaint.setColor(newColor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> it does not pick the color on 1st selection
>    but some how it is selected when i reopen the color dialog

Because no event is fire when `onOk` Button of `AmbilWarnaDialog` is click in `myActivity` for updating color of View which is selected from Dilaog

Create a custom event listener by using interface,implement it in Activity from which showing Alert, and calling listener method from   onOk` Button click by passing selected color value.

See following example for creating custom event listener :

[Custom event listener on Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app)