# Make Asynctask return Cursor

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have written an Asynctask to fetch data from db and return cursor. However, when I call it in my main thread and pass it to a cursor, Android studio gives me an error. I've done all this as  per the android dev docs, I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my asynctask:

```
public class FetchDataDay extends AsyncTask<DatabaseContract, Cursor, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(DatabaseContract... params) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
             cursor = params[0].getSteps(System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);

    }
}
```

And here I am calling the task:

```
 public void initday() {

   Cursor cursor = new FetchDataDay().execute(databaseHandler);
```

// this line is giving me an error saying its the wrong return type.

```
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            //doing something with the data
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cursor cursor = new FetchDataDay().execute(databaseHandler); 
> this
>   line is giving me an error saying its the wrong return type.

As see here:

[AsyncTask.execute(Params...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...)) : method return type is `void` instead of `Cursor` type.

Use `onPostExecute` for updating UI According to `doInBackground` method result.

And if `FetchDataDay` is separate class then create a [custom event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983250/custom-event-listener-on-android-app) using `interface`  which will notify in caller class when `onPostExecute` method is called.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get that. Yes, Asynctask itself does not return, but I can't override the onPostExecute to return cursor. So do I declare a global variable and then just set it in onPostExecute?

Comment: @RicheekDey: But when `Cursor cursor = new FetchDataDay().execute(databaseHandler);` line executed by system control will not want for the response of `doInBackground ` method and move to next line which is `if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {` where `cursor` object always null

Comment: @RicheekDey: you can also go with `get` method like `Cursor cursor = new FetchDataDay().execute(databaseHandler).get();` but this will freeze UI until `doInBackground ` method not executed completely

Comment: So perhaps I can do all my processing in doInBackground and then use all global variables?

Comment: @RicheekDey: Yes right. but also need an event which fire on UI Thread after execution of `doInBackground ` to update UI elements.

Comment: Right of coz. So I shifted it all to onPostExecute, which UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the work of UI thread into your onPostExecute, it should work.